# Breakable tcolorcbox: Avoid "closing" box then "opening" box on new page?

Tags: tcolorbox

The picture describes the behavior I'm looking for.  I want the box to act like it's one box on two pages instead of being two distinct boxes.  If it's some other option besides "breakable," that is fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newsavebox{\myboxbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{+b} 
{%
    \centering
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \sbox{\myboxbox}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-16mm}#1\end{varwidth}}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        breakable,
        width=\dimexpr\wd\myboxbox+8mm,
        top=3mm,
        bottom=4mm,
        ]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\\
\begin{mybox}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \end{singlespace}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the documentation. It has even examples showing this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comment Ulrkike Fisher.  Can you post the link?  Also, maybe you can post the answer to my question?  THANKS!

Comment: you can find the documentation in your tex system with `texdoc tcolorbox`, or online on ctan or on https://texdoc.org/index.html

Comment: `\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced]
...
\end{tcolorbox}`